# Modifying a matrix in groovy with multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, matrix, groovy

I have a multi-threading problem in which I should multiply 2 random matrices. The problem is that after I finish the execution the matrix is empty although if I print the element that is inserted into the matrix it is displayed right. The matrices to be multiplied are not empty.

```
import java.util.Random

p1 = 500
p2 = 500
threads = 4


def giveTasks(int workers, int tasks) {
    int[] taskArray = new int[workers + 1]
    taskArray[0] = 0
    for (i = 1; i <= workers; i++) {
        taskArray[i] = taskArray[i - 1] + tasks / workers + Math.max(tasks % workers - i + 1, 0)
    }
    return taskArray
}

class Matrix {
    public int[][] table

    public Matrix(int p1, int p2) {
        table = new int[p1][p2]
    }

    public Matrix(int[][] matrix) {
        table = matrix
    }
}

def createMatrix(int lines, int columns) {
    int[][] matrix = new int[lines][columns]
    Random rn = new Random()
    for (i = 0; i < lines; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < columns; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = rn.nextInt(100)
    return matrix
}

Matrix matrix1 = new Matrix(createMatrix(p1, p2))
Matrix matrix2 = new Matrix(createMatrix(p2, p1))
Matrix matrix = new Matrix(p1, p2)


int[] taskArray = giveTasks(threads, p1)

def thread
int tn = 0
for (int i = 1; i < threads + 1; i++) {
    start = taskArray[i - 1]
    stop = taskArray[i]

    thread = Thread.start {
        for (int job = start; job < stop; job++) { //line for matrix1
            int sum = 0
            for (int j = 0; j < p1; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < p1; k++)
                    sum += matrix1.table[job][k] + matrix2.table[k][j]
                matrix.table[job][j] = sum
            }
        }
        tn += 1
        println "Thread " + tn + "finished"
    }
}
thread.join()
print matrix.table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one major thing wrongly understood by you in the code you have shown us - you overwrite `thread` variable inside for-loop and after you spawn all 4 threads you wait only for the last one to finish execution.

Instead you should store a list of all spawned threads and you would have to join them all in the end of the script. Something like:

```
def queue = []
int tn = 0

for (int i = 1; i < threads + 1; i++) {
    start = taskArray[i - 1]
    stop = taskArray[i]

    def thread = Thread.start {
        for (int job = start; job < stop; job++) { //line for matrix1
            int sum = 0
            for (int j = 0; j < p1; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < p1; k++)
                    sum += matrix1.table[job][k] + matrix2.table[k][j]
                matrix.table[job][j] = sum
            }
        }
        tn += 1
        println "Thread " + tn + "finished"
    }

    queue << thread
}
queue*.join()
matrix.table.each { println it }
```

You can see that in the end of the script it does:

```
queue*.join()
```

It uses Groovy's spread operator to call `join()` method on all elements collected in the list. And we add every spawned thread to the `queue` list using left shift operator:

```
queue << thread
```

This is an equivalent of `queue.add(thread)`.

I have run your program with `p1=16` and `p2=16` with those changes applied and I got an output like:

```
Thread 3finished
Thread 4finished
Thread 1finished
Thread 2finished
[1470, 2794, 4343, 5924, 7388, 9015, 10533, 12064, 13713, 15672, 17354, 18916, 20524, 22086, 23370, 24982]
[1464, 2782, 4325, 5900, 7358, 8979, 10491, 12016, 13659, 15612, 17288, 18844, 20446, 22002, 23280, 24886]
[1629, 3112, 4820, 6560, 8183, 9969, 11646, 13336, 15144, 17262, 19103, 20824, 22591, 24312, 25755, 27526]
[1466, 2786, 4331, 5908, 7368, 8991, 10505, 12032, 13677, 15632, 17310, 18868, 20472, 22030, 23310, 24918]
[1487, 2828, 4394, 5992, 7473, 9117, 10652, 12200, 13866, 15842, 17541, 19120, 20745, 22324, 23625, 25254]
[1570, 2994, 4643, 6324, 7888, 9615, 11233, 12864, 14613, 16672, 18454, 20116, 21824, 23486, 24870, 26582]
[1345, 2544, 3968, 5424, 6763, 8265, 9658, 11064, 12588, 14422, 15979, 17416, 18899, 20336, 21495, 22982]
[1622, 3098, 4799, 6532, 8148, 9927, 11597, 13280, 15081, 17192, 19026, 20740, 22500, 24214, 25650, 27414]
[1557, 2968, 4604, 6272, 7823, 9537, 11142, 12760, 14496, 16542, 18311, 19960, 21655, 23304, 24675, 26374]
[1477, 2808, 4364, 5952, 7423, 9057, 10582, 12120, 13776, 15742, 17431, 19000, 20615, 22184, 23475, 25094]
[1447, 2748, 4274, 5832, 7273, 8877, 10372, 11880, 13506, 15442, 17101, 18640, 20225, 21764, 23025, 24614]
[1473, 2800, 4352, 5936, 7403, 9033, 10554, 12088, 13740, 15702, 17387, 18952, 20563, 22128, 23415, 25030]
[1727, 3308, 5114, 6952, 8673, 10557, 12332, 14120, 16026, 18242, 20181, 22000, 23865, 25684, 27225, 29094]
[1483, 2820, 4382, 5976, 7453, 9093, 10624, 12168, 13830, 15802, 17497, 19072, 20693, 22268, 23565, 25190]
[1575, 3004, 4658, 6344, 7913, 9645, 11268, 12904, 14658, 16722, 18509, 20176, 21889, 23556, 24945, 26662]
[1474, 2802, 4355, 5940, 7408, 9039, 10561, 12096, 13749, 15712, 17398, 18964, 20576, 22142, 23430, 25046]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, I didn't know how to use the join. I thought it would somehow wait all the threads in execution. Thank you.

Comment: @CodrinStrîmbei Btw, if you are interested in multithread and parallel computation using Groovy you should definitely give GPars a try - http://gpars.org/guide/guide/ It may help you learning parallel computation and give some good ideas how to do it.

Comment: Another problem with the above code is that I have to redifine start and stop(like int start = ...) in the forloop otherwise for p1=15 and p2=15 for 3 threads the tasks are not well distributed. Thank you for the gpars also.